# Redirecting mysite.ca/something/ to mysite.com/something/

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm running a single IIS7 website, it has 6 bindings.

- mysite.ca
- mysite.com
- myfrenchsite.ca
- myfrenchsite.com
- mydevsite.mydevdomain.com
- myfrenchdevsite.mydevdomain.com

I want to redirect my domains in the following way:

- mysite.ca/something/ --> mysite.com/something/
- myfrenchsite.ca/somethingelse/ --> myfrenchsite.com/somethingelse/

I'm not very good with IIS's rewrite syntax, I'm trying a bunch of things but I'm really not sure what the rules should be.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you last tested and what are the rules? (it isn't really clear from your example what you want to achieve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the rules I ended up using, simpler than expected.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysite\.ca" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myfrenchsite\.ca" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://myfrenchsite.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="No www 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.myfrenchsite)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://myfrenchsite.com{PATH_INFO}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="no www 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.mysite)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com{PATH_INFO}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```